# How to enumerate all elements of ND-array without hardcoding number of dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I know the number of dimensions, say, `3`, I an hardcode it with 3 nested loops:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
   for j in range(A.shape[1]):
      for k in range(A.shape[2]):
          A[i,j,k] = some_formula(i, j, k)
```

But what if I don't know the number of dimensions? Can I still enumerate array with knowing all indices on each loop?

Comment: `numpy.ndenumerate`?

Comment: You should really be using NumPy broadcasting instead of looping over the array at Python level.

Comment: `len(A.shape)` will return the number of dimension. And you even don't have to write indices like A.shape[0] manually. There are two way, use numpy manner(@user2357112 says) or `itertools.product` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function broadcasts, you can use [`numpy.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html):

```
B = numpy.fromfunction(some_formula, A.shape, dtype=int)
```

If your function doesn't broadcast, you can use `numpy.vectorize` and `numpy.fromfunction`, but it'll be a lot less efficient than if your function broadcasted naturally:

```
B = numpy.fromfunction(numpy.vectorize(some_formula), A.shape, dtype=int)
```